# Is mouseEvent created by human?

Tags: javascript, events, click, mouseevent, bots

It's well known that you can check whether trigger click is made by human or not.

```
if(event.originalEvent !== undefined){ alert('human'); }
```

But is it possible to check if mouseEvent is made by human or bot? Example of creating mouseEvent below.

```
var mousedownEvent = document.createEvent ("MouseEvent");
    mousedownEvent.initMouseEvent ("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, x, y, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    element.dispatchEvent(mousedownEvent);
```

Comment: No, in both cases, an identical mouseEvent would get fired.

Comment: Yes though somewhat clunky, there are some functions that require a human interaction (eg full screen) you can not fake these events. Only user created events will let you access fullscreen, so if the attempt to fullscreen fails you know you have programmatically generated event. But I would hope there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

No, at least not simply by looking just at the event. The structure of the event would be the same regardless of how it was generated.

It would be possible to apply some heuristic measures to analyze the movements of the mouse and determine if it was a human or a bot (bots are much more likely to move in more consistent, perfectly straight lines, whereas humans are more likely to move with a slight curve or randomness). This is actually part of how Google's "Not a Robot" captcha works.

However, doing something like that would go well beyond the scope of a single question here.

Comment: Next step I was about to do was checking movements of the users mouse. Thanks for response ;)